# _toString() PHP function

Tags: php, tostring

Here is my _toString() function.  I can't find anything wrong with it but I keep getting an error in my browser when I try to echo an obj of this class saying "Catchable fatal error: Object of class Fraction could not be converted to string in."

```
public function _toString ()
{
    $str = "";
    if(($this->num/$this->den) >= 1)
    {
        $tmp = ((int)($this->num/$this->den));
        $str .= "{$tmp} ";    
    }

    if ($this->num%$this->den != 0)
    {
        $tmp =$this->num % $this->den;
        $str .= "{$tmp} / {$this->den}";
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Could it be something wrong with my function or is it something else?  Thanks.

(This is for a fraction class I am trying to represent in a string.  $num is the numerator and $den is the denominator)

Comment: What are you wanting the function to do?

Answer (score 3):

Try using an [extra underscore](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) out front of your function definition:

```
public function __toString () {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with a double underscore: `__toString()`

Answer (score 1):

There should be two underscores, to make it magic. `__toString()`